# Pivot Table (Data Model) cannot calculate formula

Tags: excel, pivot, calculated-field

I have 2 tables that would want to be joint as pivot. I have put in data model and both of the table are in the pivot table. But when I want to calculate fields in Analzye>Fields,Items,Sets>Calculated Field, I can't click on the calculated field even though my data has numbers.

Comment: did you click a field within the pivot table before go to the calculated field option?

Comment: Yes, I have clicked it

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is a Programming forum, where is your programming issue? You should ask it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)